# Pandas Search Specific Columns for String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to search through specific columns in my DataFrame. If any of these columns contains the keyword "Matched" I would then like to write to the column "Result" with a "Yes"

Current DF

```
Result Google    Bing    Search
       Matched   Matched Matched

       Matched   
                         Matched
```

Expected Result

```
Result Google    Bing    Search
 Yes   Matched   Matched Matched
 No   
 Yes   Matched   
 Yes                     Matched
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one value per row:

```
cols = ['Google', 'Bing', 'Search']
df['Result'] = np.where(df[cols].eq('Matched').any(axis=1), 'Yes','No')
print (df)
  Result   Google     Bing   Search
0    Yes  Matched  Matched  Matched
1     No      NaN      NaN      NaN
2    Yes  Matched      NaN      NaN
3    Yes      NaN  Matched      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension like this:

```
df['Result'] = ['Yes' if len(i) >= 1 else 'No' for i in df.values.tolist()]
```

Comment: ok deleteing! good luck and thank you for contributing to the community!